# Is this lock usage thread safe?

Tags: c#, synchronization, locking

I know that is wrong to use `lock(this)` or any shared object.

I wonder if this usage is OK?

```
public class A
{
  private readonly object locker = new object();
  private List<int> myList;
  public A()
  {
    myList = new List<int>()
  }

  private void MethodeA()
  {
    lock(locker)
    {
      myList.Add(10);
    }
  }

  public void MethodeB()
  {
    CallToMethodInOtherClass(myList);
  }
}

public class OtherClass
{
  private readonly object locker = new object();
  public CallToMethodInOtherClass(List<int> list)
  {
   lock(locker)
   {
     int i = list.Count;
   }
  }
}
```

Is this thread safe? In `OtherClass` we lock with a private object so if the `class A` lock with its private lock can the list still change in the the lock block in `OtherClass`?

Comment: Your bathroom has two doors, each with a lock. Your question is "suppose I only lock the first lock when I am in the shower, and my friend Bob only locks the second lock when he is in the shower. Can we ever both end up in the shower at the same time?" Obviously yes! If you and Bob want to avoid showering together then you need to agree to both use *the same lock*. You can't make access to an object threadsafe like this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it's not thread safe. Add and Count may be executed at the "same" time. You have two different lock objects.

Always lock your own lock object when passing the list:

```
  public void MethodeB()
  {
    lock(locker)
    {
      CallToMethodInOtherClass(myList);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It actually is thread-safe, though only as an implementation detail of `Count` being thread-safe which isn't promised, and not in a way that would extend well into more realistic code.

Answer (score 4):

No this is not thread safe. To make it thread safe you can use lock on `static` objects because they are shared between threads, this may cause deadlocks in the code but it can be handle by maintaining proper order for locking. There is a performance cost associated with `lock` so use it wisely.

Hope this helps

Comment: Static objects are shared among other object, so if you put lock on this, it will be consume by only one object at one time. Read more about [static on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx) or [lock on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.80).aspx) (_Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances._ MSDN)

Comment: Great... Use `lock` whenever it is absolutely necessary, there is performance impact when using it.

Comment: This is less thread-safe. Aside from the locking object being broader than necessary you've exposed the locking object so it's now possible for different outside code to use it in different ways alongside other locking objects making deadlock possible.

Comment: +1 That's right, I was explaining the use of `static` object in case of `lock`, ideally all the lock object should have limited scope.

Comment: @Amar but shared objects can make deadlocks. see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188793.aspx)

Comment: Yes right, that's why I mentioned it should be use wisely. It's upto developer how to use `lock` for synchronization. If you don't want to do synchronization yourself, you can use data types such [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) which are threadsafe.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure: The performance cost of an uncontended lock is 20 to 80 **nanoseconds**. Uncontended locks are usually not a performance problem.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure: hash tables are not threadsafe in general. Some may be threadsafe for *readers only* scenarios; consult the documentation for details.

Comment: @Maya: shared objects do not cause deadlocks. **Improper lock ordering** causes deadlocks.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure Hashtable is thread-safe for a single writing thread and many readers. While that's not an unheard-of combination, its not unheard-of to have multiple writers to a dictionary-style collection like hashtable either. And even then, as I point out in my answer, combinations of thread-safe operations can easily combine to no longer be thread-safe.

Comment: @EricLippert it is true though that the smaller the set of code to which a lock is visible, the easier it to avoid improper ordering. The exposure of `LockObject.Locker` above makes it even possible for two pieces of code in different assemblies to acquire it and another lock, in a different order. With private lock objects its much easier to analyse the code to be sure that that never happens.

Comment: If the locking object is *private* static it won't be visible externally.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not thread-safe. `A.MethodeA` and `OtherClass.CallToMethodInOtherClass` are locking on different objects, so they're not mutually exclusive. If you need to protect the access to the list, don't pass it to external code, keep it private.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not thread-safe.

Your 2 methods are locking on 2 different objects, they will not lock out each other.

Because `CallToMethodInOtherClass()` only retrieves the value of Count nothing will go horribly wrong. But the `lock()` around it is useless and misleading.

If the method would make changes in the list you would have a nasty problem. To solve it, change MethodeB:

```
  public void MethodeB()
  {
    lock(locker)  // same instance as MethodA is using
    {
      CallToMethodInOtherClass(myList);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, they have to lock the same object. With your code they both lock on a different and each call could be executed simultaneous.

To make the code thread safe place a lock in MethodeB or use the list itself as lock object.

Comment: @ Felix I thoought that its wrong to lock with shared object so lock with the list itself its wrong?

Comment: @Maya That's true, it's wrong. But it's a easy way to solve the problem described. But anyway the right way would be to create a thread-safe list or a container which contains the list and access the list only over the container.

Answer (score 1):

It actually is thread-safe (purely as a matter of an implementation detail on `Count`), but:

1. Thread-safe snippets of code do not a thread-safe application make. You can combine different thread-safe operations into non-thread-safe operations. Indeed, much non-thread-safe code can be broken down into smaller pieces all of which are thread-safe on their own.
2. It's not thread-safe for the reason you were hoping, which means that extending it further would not be thread-safe.

This code would be thread-safe:

```
public void CallToMethodInOtherClass(List<int> list)
{
   //note we've no locks!
   int i = list.Count;
   //do something with i but don't touch list again.
}
```

Call it with any list, and it'll give `i` a value based on the state of that list, regardless of what other threads are up to. It will not corrupt `list`. It will not give `i` an invalid value.

So while this code is also thread-safe:

```
public void CallToMethodInOtherClass(List<int> list)
{
  Console.WriteLine(list[93]); // obviously only works if there's at least 94 items
                            // but that's nothing to do with thread-safety
}
```

This code would not be thread-safe:

```
public void CallToMethodInOtherClass(List<int> list)
{
   lock(locker)//same as in the question, different locker to that used elsewhere.
   {
     int i = list.Count;
     if(i > 93)
       Console.WriteLine(list[93]);
   }
}
```

Before going further, **the two bits I described as thread-safe are not promised to be by the spec for List**. Conservative coding would assume they are not thread-safe rather than depending upon implementation details, but I'm going to depend on the implementation details because it affects the question of how to use locks in an important way:

Because there is code operating on `list` that is not acquiring the lock on `locker` first, that code is not prevented from running concurrently with `CallToMethodInOtherClass`. Now, while `list.Count` is thread-safe and `list[93]` is tread-safe,* the combination of the two where we depend on the first to ensure that the second works is not thread-safe. Because code outside the lock can affect `list`, it's possible for code to call `Remove` or `Clear` in between `Count` assuring us that `list[93]` would work, and `list[93]` being called.

Now, if we know that `list` is only ever added to, that's fine, even if a resize is happening concurrently we'll end up with the value of `list[93]` either way. If something is writing to `list[93]` and it's a type that .NET will write to atomically (and `int` is one such type), we'll end up with either the old one or the new one, just as if we'd locked correctly we'd get the old or the new depending on which thread go the lock first. **Again, this is an implementation detail not a specified promise**, I'm stating this just to point out how the thread-safety given still results in non thread-safe code.

Moving this toward real code. We shouldn't assume that `list.Count` and `list[93]` is threadsafe because we weren't promised they would be and that could change, but even if we did have that promise, those two promises won't add up to a promise that they'd be thread-safe together.

The important thing is to use the same lock to protect blocks of code that can interfere with each other. Hence, consider the variant below that is guaranteed to be threadsafe:

```
public class ThreadSafeList
{
  private readonly object locker = new object();
  private List<int> myList = new List<int>();

  public void Add(int item)
  {
    lock(locker)
      myList.Add(item);
  }
  public void Clear()
  {
    lock(locker)
      myList.Clear();
  }
  public int Count
  {
    lock(locker)
      return myList.Count;
  }
  public int Item(int index)
  {
    lock(locker)
      return myList[index];
  }
}
```

This class is guaranteed to be thread-safe in everything it does. Without depending on any implementation details, there is no method here that will corrupt state or give incorrect results because of what another thread is doing with the same instance. The following code **still** doesn't work though:

```
// (l is a ThreadSafeList visible to multiple threads.
if(l.Count > 0)
  Console.WriteLine(l[0]);
```

We've guaranteed the thread-safety of each call 100%, but we haven't guaranteed the combination, and we *can't* guarantee the combination.

There's two things we can do. We can add a method for the combination. Something like the following would be common for many classes specifically designed for multi-threaded use:

```
public bool TryGetItem(int index, out int value)
{
  lock(locker)
  {
    if(l.Count > index)
    {
      value = l[index];
      return true;
    }
    value = 0;
    return false;
  }
}
```

This makes the count test and the item retrieval part of a single operation which is guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Alternatively, and most often what we need to do, we have the lock happen at the place where the operations are grouped:

```
lock(lockerOnL)//used by every other piece of code operating on l
  if(l.Count > 0)
    Console.WriteLine(l[0]);
```

Of course, this makes the locks within `ThreadSafeList` redundant and just a waste of effort, space, and time. This is the main reason that most classes don't provide thread-safety on their instance members - since you can't meaningfully protect groups of calls on members from within the class, it's a waste of time trying to unless the thread-safety promises are very well specified and useful on their own.

To come back to the code in your question:

The lock in `CallToMethodInOtherClass` should be removed unless `OtherClass` has its own reason for locking internally. It can't make a meaningful promise that it won't be combined in a non-threadsafe way and adding more locks to a program just increases the complexity of analysing it to be sure there are no deadlocks.

The call to `CallToMethodInOtherClass` should be protected by the same lock as other operations in that class:

```
public void MethodeB()
{
  lock(locker)
    CallToMethodInOtherClass(myList);
}
```

Then as long as `CallToMethodInOtherClass` doesn't store `myList` somewhere it can be seen by other threads later on, it doesn't matter that `CallToMethodInOtherClass` isn't thread-safe because the only code that can access `myList` brings its own guarantee not to call it concurrently with other operations on `myList`.

The two important things are:

1. When something is described as "thread-safe", know just what it's promising by that, as there are different sorts of promise that fall under "thread-safe" and on its own it just means "I won't put this object into a nonsensical state", which while an important building block, is not a lot on its own.
2. Lock on *groups* of operations, with the same lock for each group that'll affect the same data, and guard the access to objects so that there can't possibly be another thread not playing ball with this.

*This is a very limited definition of thread-safe. Calling `list[93]` on a `List<T>` where `T` is a type that will be written and read atomically and we don't know whether it actually has at least 94 items is equally safe whether or not there are other threads operating on it. Of course, the fact that it can throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in either case is not what most people would consider "safe", but the guarantee we have with multiple threads remains the same as with one. It's that we obtain a stronger guarantee by checking `Count` in a single thread but not in a multi-thread situation that leads me to describe that as not thread-safe; while that combo still won't corrupt state it can lead to an exception we'd assured ourselves couldn't happen.

Comment: Use ConcurrentBag or ConcurrentDictionary instead, then you won't have to worry about locking.

Comment: @PålThingbø Not true in the slightest. First while those collections, and indeed my own [thread-safe dictionary and set](https://bitbucket.org/JonHanna/ariadne) and some other such collections, are thread-safe for each individual action on them, groups of actions on them are not necessarily thread-safe for the reasons I give above (think about it, `int` is thread-safe, but that doesn't make `++x` thread-safe, because the three thread-safe actions that entails are not thread-safe as a unit). There's also rarely much point suggesting someone use a bag or dictionary when they want a list; the...

Comment: @PålThingbø semantics of those classes are completely different. I will hopefully be releasing a thread-safe list class soon that gives much better concurrent behaviour than that in the answer above, though it will still be limited (no `RemoveAt` or `Insert`; I might produce a different class that has them too later, but doing them thread-safe without locking is much more cumbersome than the rest), and it still won't make code using it magically thread-safe as a whole, any more than `ConcurrentDictionary` does, again for the reasons I give above.

Comment: Thanks @Jon for the clarification. I was giving advise based on the code in question, which is simply adding and removing items to a collection. Concurrent is a great tool for this.

Comment: @PålThingbø since the code in the question just adds the value `10`, the best complete replacement is one that just keeps count of how many `10`s were added! In terms of real code, I suppose your guess that they don't need list semantics is as good as my guess that they do. Still, concurrent objects do still need care to make sure sets of operations one does with them are still thread-safe as a whole.

Comment: I agree. I guessed that he just wanted the collection, and that List.Count was what he was looking for. Anyway, love your code, and keep up the good work.

Comment: @PålThingbø `ConcurrentBag.Count` can be one thing one gets most tripped up on with careless use. Thanks for the compliment; that project has been quiet lately, but will be busy for a while as I'm doing a refactor and then will finally mark it "1.0" soon (after which I'll be a lot stricter about breaking changes). Do feel free to suggest changes (patches or pull-requests).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do the trick

```
public class A
{
  private List<int> myList;
  public A()
  {
    myList = new List<int>()
  }

  private void MethodeA()
  {
    lock(myList)
    {
      myList.Add(10);
    }
  }

  public void MethodeB()
  {
    CallToMethodInOtherClass(myList);
  }
}

public class OtherClass
{
  public CallToMethodInOtherClass(List<int> list)
  {
   lock(list)
   {
     int i = list.Count;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: but i thought its wront to lock with shraed object

Answer (score 0):

Ass all the answers say these are different lock objects.

a simple way is to have a static lock object f.ex:

```
publc class A
{
    public static readonly object lockObj = new object();
}
```

and in both classes use lock like:

```
lock(A.lockObj)
{
}
```

Comment: You should avoid having locking objects exposed as *public*. If your intention is solely the thread synchronization, the locking object should be private.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers have mentioned using a static readonly lock.

However, you really should try to avoid this static lock. It would be easy to create a deadlock where multiple threads are using the static lock.

What you could use instead is one of the .net 4 concurrent collections, these do provide some thread synchronisation on your behalf, so that you do not need to use the locking.

Take a look at the `System.collections.Concurrent` namespace.
For this example, you could use the `ConcurrentBag<T>` class.